# ASP.net hiding panel using javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, panel, radiobuttonlist

I have a radioButtonList with 2 items in it. A radiobutton with a "Yes" value and a radionButton with a "No" value.

Below that I have a panel which I want made visible when "Yes" radioButton is selected and hidden when "No" is selected. I had originally implemented this using the AutoPostBack attribute but I want to do it in Javascript so that it doesn't cause a postback. Here's the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl1" runat="server" onClick="changed(this);" >
<asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>

<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server">
<--other controls here -->
</asp:Panel>

function changed(rbl) {
        //not sure what to put in here
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Zaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example I made up:

```
<!-- Used grouped radio buttons instead of the RadioButtonList as it is harder to deal with -->
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="YourGroupName" Checked="true" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbNo" runat="server" Text="No" GroupName="YourGroupName" />        
<br /><br />    
<!-- Use a div instead of a panel.  Panels are just glorified divs. -->
<div id="divTest">
    This is a test
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#<%= rbYes.ClientID %>').click(function() { $('#divTest').show(); });
        $('#<%= rbNo.ClientID %>').click(function() { $('#divTest').hide(); });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    function OnclickPanelHide() {
        if (this.value == "No") {
            document.getElementByID('<%=panel1.ClientID%>').style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementByID('<%=panel1.ClientID%>').style.display = "block";
        }
    }


</script>
```

Raja There is some bug in your code i just removed it

Comment: This should be a comment or edit on the Raja answer. Please read through this: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class or determine the real id of "panel1", you can use jQuery to hide it easily:

```
$('idOfPanel').hide();
```

Or you without using jQuery, using the id of the div/panel:

```
idOfPanel.style.display = "none";
```

To redisplay:

```
$('idOfPanel').show();
```

Or

```
idOfPanel.style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (this.value == "No")
{
document.getElementByID('<%=panel1.ClientId%').style.display = "none";
}
else
{
document.getElementByID('<%=panel1.ClientId%').style.display = "block";
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind doing a partial postback, you can also throw your code into an `UpdatePanel` (assuming that you don't want to postback so that the entire page doesn't have to go through a page life-cycle).